# Basic operation of low pass filters?

Tags: low-pass

Suppose you have a resistor that leads to a parallel connection of a capacitor and an output wire. I am having tremendous difficulty understanding how the capacitor steals all the current that would not otherwise leak into the output wire, reproducing the frequency that entered in, only with a different amplitude from the resistor. Does the capacitor simply build up to its maximum capacitance and then release all at once when the buildup leads to the repelling of electrons? It's a parallel circuit. The voltage is running through to both the output and the capacitor, so wouldn't the capacitor actually increase the frequency of the input from those releases?

Comment: "parallel connection of a capacitor and an output wire"  err, what? show a schematic of what you mean, that makes no sense

Comment: Familiarize yourself with the classic voltage divider.  Then, how the impedance of a capacitor varies with frequency.  Then, replace the lower resistor in the voltage divider with a capacitor, and think about it some more...

Comment: Given Q = C * V, differentiate that to produce I = C * dV/dT (discard the part with variable C). Drive that capacitor from the limited current available from the resistor, and make T progressively smaller and smaller and smaller.

Answer (score 2):

> I am having tremendous difficulty understanding how the capacitor
>   steals all the current that would not otherwise leak into the output
>   wire....

When ever you design a passive filter (RC, RL etc.) you have to take into account the impedance of the loading circuit and the impedance of the feeding circuit. If you don't do this you get the wrong filter performance.

> .... reproducing the frequency that entered in, only with a different
>   amplitude from the resistor.

Yes, that is what happens if the loading impedance is significant compared to the filter component impedances. This is why many filters are designed to feed a high load impedance such as an op-amp. On the other hand, a passive cross-over filter inside a speaker has to deal with very low impedances (such as 8 ohm) and, as such, has to use different (and usually more complex) design equations.

Regarding the capacitor concept. If you just think of it as an impedance that lowers linearly with applied frequency, it should all make sense.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to think of a capacitor... One is a charge storage device, the other is an impedance that is proportional to the applied signal frequency. I think you are dwelling on the former, which is not so applicable when a capacitor is used in a filter application.

I am assuming from your description that your circuit looks like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkbdLL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this case the circuit is applied an AC signal and as such the capacitor is operating as a variable impedance. The circuit can therefore be represented as the following.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCiVXi.png)</sup>

As you can see you now have a resistor divider between \$R1\$ and \$X_c\$, the impedance of the capacitor at the applied signal frequency.

\$X_c = 1/(2 * \pi * f * C)\$

Since \$X_c\$ diminishes as frequency increases the output is attenuated for higher frequencies.

Note the DELAY in the circuit. In addition to attenuating the signal there is a phase shift created by the capacitor. Since it takes a finite time for the capacitor to charge up and down as it follows the signal the output signal is effectively delayed relative to the input signal.

The phase shift will be governed by the equation..

\$\varphi  = -arctan(2*\pi * f * R * C)\$

There is a good tutorial on simple filter theory [here](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_2.html).